# Time-series average of cross-sectional correlations

Tags: r, time-series, correlation

I have a panel dataset looking like this:

```
head(panel_data)

        date      symbol   close  rv   rv_plus rv_minus rskew rkurt  Mkt.RF  SMB   HML
    1 1999-11-19    a      25.4  19.3    6.76    12.6  -0.791  4.36  -0.11  0.35  -0.5 
    2 1999-11-22    a      26.8  10.1    6.44    3.69   0.675  5.38   0.02  0.22  -0.92
    3 1999-11-23    a      25.2  8.97    2.56    6.41  -1.04   4.00  -1.29  0.08   0.3 
    4 1999-11-24    a      25.6  5.81    2.86    2.96  -0.505  5.45   0.87  0.08  -0.89
    5 1999-11-26    a      25.6  2.78    1.53    1.25   0.617  5.60   0.23  0.92  -0.2 
    6 1999-11-29    a      26.1  5.07    2.76    2.30  -0.236  7.27  -0.6   0.570 -0.14
```

where the variable symbol depicts different stocks. I want to calculate the time-series average of the cross-sectional correlation between the variables rskew and rkurt. This means I need to compute the correlation between rskew and rkurt over all different stocks at each point in time and then calculate the time-series average afterwards.

I tried to do it with the `rollapply` function from the `zoo` package, but since the number of different stocks is not the same for all dates, I  cannot simply define `width` as an integer. Here is what i tried for a sample `width` of 20:

```
panel_data <- panel_data %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(cor_skew_kurt = rollapply(data = panel_data[7:8],
                         width=20,
                         FUN=cor,
                         align="right",
                         na.rm=TRUE,
                         fill=NA)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Is there a way to do this without having to define a fixed `width` for each date group?

Or should I maybe use a different approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Edited]** Can you try running the below code? I have recreated an example emulating your issue.  if I understood your problem correctly this code should at least put you on the path to the right solution as it solves the issue of unequal time window length.

```
###################
#Recreating an example dataset with unequal dates across stocks
seed(1)
date6 <- c('1999-11-19','1999-11-22','1999-11-23','1999-11-24','1999-11-26','1999-11-29')
date5 <- c('1999-11-19','1999-11-22','1999-11-23','1999-11-24','1999-11-26')
date4 <- c('1999-11-19','1999-11-22','1999-11-23','1999-11-24')
cor_skew_kurt <- c(rep(NaN,21))
symbol <- c(rep('a',6),rep('b',5),rep('c',4),rep('d',6))
rskew <- rnorm(21,mean=1, sd =1)
rkurt <- rnorm(21, mean=5, sd = 1)
panel_data <- cbind.data.frame(date = c(date6,date5,date4,date6), symbol = symbol, rskew = rskew, rkurt = rkurt, cor_skew_kurt = cor_skew_kurt )
panel_data$date <- as.Date(panel_data$date, '%Y-%m-%d')


# Computing the cor_skew_kurt and filling the table  <- ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION

for (date in unique(panel_data$date))
{
   panel_data[panel_data$date == date,"cor_skew_kurt"] <-  as.double(cor(panel_data[panel_data$date == date,'rskew'],panel_data[panel_data$date == date,'rkurt']))
  
}
```

Comment: This gives me the following error message `n() must only be used inside dplyr verbs`, since `rollapply` is from the `zoo` package.

Comment: @Kharon - Okay so I just edited my post to provide a full answer to your question. I may have been a bit unclear on your desired final output but this code solves the issue of unequal time window length so it should put you on the right path. Just let me know if you expected the output to be under a different format.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is there a possibility to extend your approach in way such that it also provides a p-value for each of the correlations? I tried this using `cor.test`, but it didn`t seem to work.